# Which version of Java is needed for Android Studio 3.5?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.5

It's been a few years since I did Android development, but I want to get back into it.

Latest version of Android Studio is 3.5.  Which version of JDK and JRE should I install first (if any)?  [Oracle JDK download page](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) has versions 7, 8, 11, 12, and 13 listed.

I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Any from list. I use the 13th.

Comment: only you can't use 13'es features in Android app, you still will use a syntax of old standard (seems 8)

Comment: Anything >= 8. I use 12.

Comment: non ... AS installs it's own JRE ... JDK is not needed for AS running(but needed for developing for android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No pre-requisite install of the JDK or JRE appears to be required anymore.

Tried this on a clean Windows 10 machine.  Somewhere between the install of Android Studio 3.5, first build, and first run in the emulator, javac.exe and java.exe versoin 1.8.202 got downloaded and installed into the `Android Studio\jre\bin` folder.